# If I get a tourist visa to Israel prior to traveling can I still get denied entry to Israel?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, israel, denial-of-entry

I heard that it's always a good idea -regardless of your destination- to get a visa to the country you traveling to prior to your travel even if it was the case that you can get a visa upon arrival as you might get refused entry.

But I get the visa before traveling is there a chance that I could be refused entry ?

> It is for the Israeli authorities to determine the right of entry into
>   Israel, if you have any particular concerns about visas or entry into
>   Israel, you should contact the Israeli Embassy in London.

[Foreign travel advice Israel](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/israel/entry-requirements)

So if the embassy said yes, airport officials wouldn't be able to say no?

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, I would be curious to know where you "heard" this from. I am not familiar with visa-on-arrival systems, but in cases where you qualify for *visa-free* entry to a country (not the same thing), it is typically not possible to obtain a visa.

Comment: @fkraiem I assume he means, for example, like when I went to Iran last month. You need a visa.  You *can* get a visa on arrival (fill out form, pay money), but sometimes get refused, so it's arguably better to try and sort it out in advance if possible.

Comment: @fkraiem exactly what Mark said, I hate to get sent back, if I am getting refused then I prefer to know that beforehand while I am home in the UK

Comment: Wouldn't this apply to any country, not just Israel?

Comment: @Scimonster yep, although with slightly different rules. Israel has some quite specific 'enemies' and guidelines on who might enter given their tense political situation, while a relatively more open country like NZ is less likely to refuse on political grounds.  Regardless, the airport authorities/officials in NZ can still say no, they just would potentially have different reasons for saying so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like any country, a visa is just an endorsement allowing you a specific period of time in a country based on your citizenship (and other potential factors).

However, once you're at the border, the border agents / authorities can and will still make a further assessment.  They might evaluate:

- your ability to support yourself while in the country
- your intent in the country (you might be on a tourist visa, but they suspect you're coming to work/do business)
- your possessions (eg if found with something illegal)
- your history (some countries won't let you in if your passport shows you've been to countries that they're not fans of)

as a result, yes, even if you have a legitimate visa, it's still possible (generally unlikely, but possible) for you to be rejected at the border.

For another question we have which is related to this, see [Being denied entry to Israel due to political activism?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/30504/101)

Comment: To put it bluntly, a visa is not a right to enter a country. It is a document that allows you the permission to go to the border to request entry. The final decision is still left to the border police/authority.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yep, a succinct summary :)